# Laravel .htaccess configuration in folders

Tags: php, laravel, apache, .htaccess

Situation: webproject where this is the folder structure.

- www

  - 2015
  - 2016
  - 2017
  - 2018
  - current

Each folder represents the website of that year, in the "current" folder it is the website that should be shown when you go to www.mydomain.com.
The goal is that if you go to www.mydomain.com/2017 you see the website of 2017.

There is a .htaccess file in the root folder that makes sure that if you navigate to the "/" you will be redirected to the current one.

I am struggling with the .htaccess file I have to put in the "2017" folder (which is a laravel application).

.htaccess file in www folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
   RewriteEngine on

   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ current/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

.htaccess file in 2017 folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
   RewriteBase /2017
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Current result: when I go to www.mydomain.com/2017, I go to the 2017 folder, but it goes to page "2017" of 2017. To test this I just added this in my web.php route:

```
Route::get('/{page}', array('as'=>'renderpage',function ($page) {
    dd('I am here and the page you request is '.$page);
}));
```

which results in:
"I am here and the page you request is 2017"

So long story short: how can I remove the "2017" from the url in the .htaccess file, so that laravel interprets www.mydomain.com/2017 as the root of the 2017 folder. Preferably this should be done in the .htaccess file in the 2017 folder.

edit:
I changed the .htaccess file in the 2017 folder to this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
   RewriteBase /2017
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule ^(/.*|)$ public/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

now it works, except in the url you now see www.mydomain.com/2017/public
how can I remove the "public" from the url?

Comment: If I understood you correct, you want that when someone requests `www.mydomain.com`, then it should directly go to `2017` folder and execute further?

Comment: @vivek_23  no I misexplained in that case... if you go to www.mydomain.com you should go to "current" (and that works). If you go to www.mydomain.com/2017 you should go to 2017. That is also what is happening, but actually you go to the "2017" page inside the 2017 folder and it should go to the 'root' page of 2017.

Comment: @AndriesHeylen Whenever it comes to Laravel routes, you can't make it to interpret requests as folders. It's a URL path and has no relation with folders. Your `Route::get('/{page}'` perfectly matches with `www.mydomain.com/2017` with `{page}` becoming `2017` here. However, you can handle the value, that is, `page` value in a Laravel controller or in a closure and redirect user properly.

Comment: @AndriesHeylen Also, why are `2016`,`2017` etc outside of `current`?

Comment: @vivek_23 because that is how we did it until now, each year the "current" folder is renamed to the last year and there is an install of a new website in the current folder.

Comment: Not sure if I got you right even now. `www.mydomain.com` points to the `current` folder which I assume is a Laravel project in itself. Then if someone requests `www.mydomain.com/2017`, then you would like to execute the `public/index.php` inside `2017` folder which is outside of `current` folder. Am I right?

Comment: @vivek_23 yes that is 100% correct.

Comment: This way you are trying to reach another Laravel project via current Laravel project which is highly discouraged. I would instead suggest you to create `subdomains` like `2017.mydomain.com` etc and point this subdomain to `www/2017/public` folder in your hosting account. This is the best way in my opinion to show them previous years' site.

Comment: @vivek_23 I suggested that as well, but that is not in the requirement of the customer. He really wants it to work with www.mydomain.com/2017 etc etc

Comment: @vivek_23 just for your information, if I go to www.mydomain.com/2017 I get to the 2017 folder, but the weird thing is that I get to the 2017 page of the 2017 folder. If in Laravel I add a "Route prefix" it actually works, but I would prefer a solution where I don't need to touch the laravel code, and it can 'simply' work with .htaccess files.

Comment: Discuss with the client once more since this is a very weird way to go about it. I would suggest you to do it the other way than .htaccess. Point your `www.mydomain.com` to `/www/` only and keep a `index.php` file inside this folder along with other folders. Using `$_SERVER` and basic string methods, retrieve the year and have a `switch` case. If there is no year mentioned, meaning it goes in the `default` section of your switch case, you could `current_folder` using `include_once()`, else include respective year's index.php which would further handle the request automatically.

Comment: @vivek_23 the requirements cannot be changed (I discussed with the customer) however I found something, but it is not 100% correct yet. Can you check my edited question?

Comment: I have never seen someone hide the `/public/` . I point my domain till public folder and it works well. You can ty the PHP way.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is the right way to do in laravel:

You can change the root directory in your controller or route by using

```
$this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
  return base_path().'/public_html';
});
```

you could insert an absolute path in there i guess.

Check out

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-public-path

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-base-path

Comment: and can it be done without touching the "laravel" code? I would prefer that

Comment: i thought you are searching for a laravel solution.

What about

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ 2017/public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

Or maybe you could create a symlink for index2017.php which links to the subfolder?

Answer (score 0):

Without touching laravel code, but with nginx config:

```
server {
    listen *:8080;
    server_name 2016.test.test;

    root /var/www/html/2016;
    index index.html index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
    }
} 

 server {
    listen                *:80;

    server_name           www.test.test;
    client_max_body_size 1m;

    root /var/www/html/current;
    index  index.html index.htm;

    location /2016/ {
        rewrite /2016/(.*) /$1 break;

        proxy_pass          http://2016.test.test:8080;
        proxy_redirect      off;
        proxy_set_header    Host $host;
    }
}
```

Folder structure:

```
.
├── 2015            
│   └── index.html  
├── 2016            
│   ├── index.html  
│   └── index.php   
├── 2017            
│   └── index.html  
├── current         
│   ├── index.html  
│   └── test.html   
└── index.html
```

index.php:

```
 <?php
     var_dump($_SERVER);
 ?>
```

result calling:
 http://www.test.test/2016/sample/foo/bar
 ...

```
  ...
  'SCRIPT_FILENAME' => string '/var/www/html/2016/index.php' (length=28)
  'REDIRECT_STATUS' => string '200' (length=3)
  'SERVER_NAME' => string '2016.test.test' (length=14)
  'SERVER_PORT' => string '8080' (length=4)
  'SERVER_ADDR' => string '127.0.0.1' (length=9)
  'REMOTE_PORT' => string '48598' (length=5)
  'REMOTE_ADDR' => string '127.0.0.1' (length=9)
  'SERVER_SOFTWARE' => string 'nginx/1.14.0' (length=12)
  'GATEWAY_INTERFACE' => string 'CGI/1.1' (length=7)
  'REQUEST_SCHEME' => string 'http' (length=4)
  'SERVER_PROTOCOL' => string 'HTTP/1.0' (length=8)
  'DOCUMENT_ROOT' => string '/var/www/html/2016' (length=18)
  'DOCUMENT_URI' => string '/index.php' (length=10)
  'REQUEST_URI' => string '/sample/foo/bar' (length=15)
  'SCRIPT_NAME' => string '/index.php' (length=10)
  ...
```

you see **REQUEST_URI** is just '/sample/foo/bar' without your year

This example is hardcoded to 2016, you can easily just use some regex for location in year like: `20[0-9]{2}` and replace match with the proper variable ($1 or something like this)